Debian 12 does not completely shutdown
I have installed Debian 12 (Bookworm) in a dualboot setup together with Windows 10. However, I have a randomly occurring issue which usually happens when I use the OS for 5 to 10 minutes. When I shutdown my pc (a Lenovo ThinkBook 15 ACL) I get the log displayed at the startup (the one with all the starting services etc.) and another line at the end with he message: "The system will power off now!" (or reboot, depends on what I chose) and a blinking cursor. It does not allow me to input any keys. The system at that point is pretty much unresponsive, and the only option for me is to force shutdown with the power button.
Is there a way to restore full functionality of the shutdown and reboot?

"pretty much unresponsive" you write. Could you be more precise ? BTW, should we understand that your system has been correctly shut-downed but just did not incidentally automatically powered-off ?

In /boot/grub/grub.cfg, there should be a few lines that start with linux /boot/... On those lines, is there the keyword quiet or quiet=3 or something similar? If so, remove those keywords and reboot. You should be able to see the kernel logs when it boots and shuts down. Add those logs to your question.

@MC68020 by "pretty much unresponsive" I mean that by interacting with the system (via keyboard) no response can be seen on the display, even though the cursor is blinking, meaning that the system is not halted. Plus, I tried to shutdown the system both via the "start" menu and the "shutdown now" command.

@rando I'm already viewing those logs by deleting the keywork "quiet" from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub. Is there a way I can put those in a file and analyse them further?
